# Example of using the extended euclidean alg to solve the discrete log problem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

I am interested in examples of how to use the extended euclidean alg to solve the discrete log problem.

I have found many videos, files, and sections in some books that discuss the alg, but not examples of how to apply it to the discrete log problem of types;

$$a^{x} \cong b \mod p$$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by that notation

Comment: (Sorry I mangled the links, deleted my old comments. Updated:)
Normally you can't. The group in 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms
is $(\mathbb{Z}_p, +)\,$ not $(\mathbb{Z}_p, *)$ and computing the DL in $(\mathbb{Z}_p, +)\,$ is equivalent to computing the modular multiplicative inverse, which **can** be done with the EEA.

The notations clarify the group operation in  $\mathbb{Z}_p$, as Wiki writes 
"let $G =\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the integers modulo p under addition"